# Separating barrel from crankcase

Tags: engine, motorcycle, suzuki

I'm removing the top end of my Suzuki GS500e to have it's header threads helicoiled, I've removed the cylinder head but the barrel is completely stuck to the crankcase, a friend and I can lift the engine by the barrel and shake it and its not freeing up. Since its air cooled I'm apprehensive of using wooden wedges out of fear of damaging the cooling fins. The maintenance diagrams show only the 8 studs that come up from the crankcase, through the barrel and are bolted down to the cylinder head + a pair of locating dowels but I'm not sure what those are made of, and they are not accessible anyway.

I've also knocked it about with a rubber mallet on the casting points (not fins). There is very slight movement prying from the back of the engine over the available solid surfaces. The pistons move freely.

Any ideas on how to unstick this?

Comment: Double nut or use some other nondestructive method to unthread all the studs. Most likely there is corrosion or carbon in the of the holes. Unthreading the studs would work around this.

Comment: You should be able to do those helicoils without removing the barrel from the crankcase...

Comment: Agree with either comment above. Leaving the barrels on the crankcase seems like the easiest route, though, unless there were other reasons you needed to remove the barrels. No reassembly needed. Could have left the heads in place, for that matter.

Comment: I had to get the head off to get it to the machine shop, I wasn't going to lug the whole engine down there and in situ the frame is in the way. Now its exposed seems like a fair idea to replace the base gasket and check over the pistons, rings and bores in any case?

Comment: I've lived by a maintenance mantra since I was a young buck: *If it ain't broke, don't fix it.* ... If the engine is running well enough and seems healthy, you may be bringing in more issues by tearing it apart to fix the threads for the headers. While lugging an entire engine around is a bit heavy, it would save you a ton of time and effort in getting fixed what is broken without causing other issues at the same time due to pulling it apart. I guess that's probably water under the bridge at this point.

Comment: why not helicoil the head without dismatling the motor?

Comment: All water under the bridge, dismantled, machine shopped, honed, new rings, reassembled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vini_i was right - corrosion between the stud and barrel. As last resort used wooden wedges to gently free off the barrel then the rot was obvious.